I need help sending sms data to the database in flutter
I have this flutter code that listens to sms from a particular sender Id (transactions service). I have used ReGex to get the transaction id, name, amount etc. Am trying to send the data to my API but it's not sending anything.
 void parseSms(String sms) {
    final RegExp regExp = RegExp(
      r'(?<transactionCode>[A-Z0-9]+) (?<transactionDate>\d{1,2}/\d{1,2}/\d{2}) at (?<transactionTime>\d{1,2}:\d{2} [APM]+)Ksh(?<amount>[0-9,]+\.\d{2}) received from (?<phoneNumber>\d{12}) (?<name>[\w\s]+)\. New Account balance is Ksh(?<balance>[0-9,]+\.\d{2})',
    );

    final match = regExp.firstMatch(sms);
    if (match != null) {
      setState(() {
        transactionCode = match.namedGroup('transactionCode') ?? 'N/A';
        transactionDate = match.namedGroup('transactionDate') ?? 'N/A';
        transactionTime = match.namedGroup('transactionTime') ?? 'N/A';
        amount = match.namedGroup('amount') ?? 'N/A';
        phoneNumber = match.namedGroup('phoneNumber') ?? 'N/A';
        name = match.namedGroup('name') ?? 'N/A';
        balance = match.namedGroup('balance') ?? 'N/A';
      });
      postTransactionDetails();

    }
  }

  Future<void> postTransactionDetails() async {
    try {
      final response = await http.post(
        Uri.parse(apiUrl),
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
        body: json.encode({
          'transactionCode': transactionCode,
          'transactionDate': transactionDate,
          'transactionTime': transactionTime,
          'amount': amount,
          'phoneNumber': phoneNumber,
          'name': name,
          'balance': balance,
        }),
      );

      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        print('Transaction details posted successfully');
      } else {
        print('Failed to post transaction details. Status code: ${response.statusCode}');
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print('Error posting transaction details: $e');
    }
  }


What am I doing wrong?
I have tried changing the API url from localhost to an ngrok url but it's still not working.

Keep in mind that we can't see whatever data you have in your app, so we have no easy way to debug it. That's why it's much more likely that someone can help if you first debug the problem on your own system, and then tell us the results of that. So: put a breakpoint on each line in your code, run in the debugger until it hits a breakpoint, and then check the value of each variable on that line. When you do this: what is the first line/variable that isn't what you expected it to be.
